# How to select an element's parent and the parent's siblings

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, chaining, removeall

I have this code:

```
$("#test").siblings('p').remove();
$("#test").remove();
```

How can I chain this code instead of writing it separately?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You want to use [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) in this case:

```
$("#test").siblings('p').addBack().remove();
```

---

**EDIT**

Firstly, for future visitors, if you're using jQuery version 1.8-, you're probably need to use [andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) which is the predecessor of `addBack()` for compatibility issues.

Secondly, both `end` and `addBack` will do the same task in this case but they're actually different perspective. Take a look at this HTML:

```
<div class="grandpa">
    <div class="dad">
        <div class="son">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If we're using `end()`:

```
$('.grandpa')
    .find('.dad')
        .find('.son')
        .addClass('youngster')
        .end()
    .addClass('adult')
    .end()
.addClass('oldster');
```

The result will look like this:

```
<div class="grandpa oldster">
    <div class="dad adult">
        <div class="son youngster">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when we use `end()` for `son`, we're telling jQuery that it need to go back from `son` to parent set which is `dad` and add class `adult`.

But when we use `addBack`:

```
$('.grandpa')
    .find('.dad')
        .find('.son')
        .addClass('youngster')
        .addBack()
        .addClass('adult')
        .addBack() // This simply do nothing since `addBack` is not traverse up DOM element 
        .addClass('oldster');
```

which will result in this:

```
<div class="grandpa">
    <div class="dad adult oldster">
        <div class="son youngster adult oldster">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when we call `addBack` on `son`, we're telling jQuery to push `dad` and `son` into the same room and add new class `adult` and `oldster` to both of them.

Comment: Whouldn't `.end()` be more appropriate than `.addBack()`?

Comment: @RoToRa They both do the same in this case

Answer (score 16):

The `end()` method is useful primarily when exploiting jQuery's chaining properties. When not using chaining, we can usually just call up a previous `object` by variable name, so we don't need to manipulate the stack.

The new set of elements is pushed onto a stack that is maintained inside the `object`. Each successive filtering method pushes a new element set onto the stack. If we need an older element set, we can use `end()` to pop the sets back off of the stack.

I guess with use of `.end()` like this:

```
$("#test").siblings('p').remove().end().remove();
```

You can find a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CyGy3/)

---

### Some explanation:

**Now what is happening with this code snippet above:**

Suppose this HTML markup:

```
<div id='container'>
   <div id='test'>This is supposed to be removed.</div>
   <p>And this to be removed too.</p>
</div>
```

when script executes:

```
$("#test").siblings('p').remove()
```

this block removes the sibling item `<p>` from the view, then markup will be updated like:

```
<div id='container'>
   <div id='test'>This is supposed to be removed.</div>
</div>
```

and if we chain it with `.end()`

```
$("#test").siblings('p').remove().end()
```

it gets back to the stack at `#test` div then the next part of the script gets fired

```
$("#test").siblings('p').remove().end().remove();
                             //--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----this next part
```

and `#test` gets removed from the view and your final markup output will be like:

```
<div id='container'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

May be off topic.. you can change the view of the problem:

```
$("#test, #test ~ p").remove(); // !! incorrect way, see comment below
```

**Guys sorry :( my decision isn't correct!!**

Selector '**~**' isn't equal '**sibling**'-method. '**~**' selects all sibling '**p**'-elements that follow **AFTER** the '**#test**' element.

So i suggest another decision:

```
$("#test, > p", $('#test').parent()).remove();
```

It is not enough elegant but the most faster way. Please check it 'http://jsperf.com/how-to-chain-this-code-stackoverflow-16009101'

Performance test result:

[image: Performance test result]

PS http://jsfiddle.net/Dpe59/

Comment: I like this answer - get the job done, without using more jQuery constructs

Answer (score 7):

I have to agree with the comment on the question; for readability and maintainability, use [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/):

```
$("#test").siblings('p').andSelf().remove();
```

Unfortunately, it's been deprecated.  But if you're stuck on an older version of jquery like we are, it *may* be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#text").siblings('p').remove().prevObject.remove();
```

**edit:**
Though this works, don't do this. as  Matt's comment says, `prevObject` is undocumented

Comment: Note that `prevObject` is completely undocumented; it could be changed or removed in later versions. `end()` on the otherhand, is documented, and *is* the preferred way to return to the previous jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#test").siblings("p").siblings("#test").remove();
```

Comment: in some situations this also is an alternative :)

Comment: your decision isn't correct it will remove only '#test'-element. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#test").siblings('p').addBack().remove();
```